# picklist (MULTIPLE SELECTIONS WITH CUSTOM OBJECT DATA)

Tags: community, custom-object, dynamic-picklist

Is there a way to create an Option List (multiple selection), in which the list items are the records of an object?
Ex:
MyObject__C
my item 01
my item 02
my item 03
my item 04

list of options (my object):
available:
my item 01 ,
my item 02 ,
my item 03 ,
my item 04 ,

selected:
my item 01 ,
my item 04,

Comment: You will have to write code at some level to do this. There is no out of the box functionality that provides this capability.

Comment: You could also try some free apps from the AppExchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=junction&searchType=simpleSearch